# Flutter Web Chrome issue

Tags: html, flutter, google-chrome, dart, web

I am developing a cross platform app using Flutter and Dart, the app runs smoothly on both Android and Ios, but when I try to run on Chrome I get the following problem:

> A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. In a future version of Chrome, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.

> To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.

> Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.

> **1 source:
> stack_trace_mapper.js:1**

I don't have access to the above file any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you manage to fix it?